# Working with Hammock and AgFx for Windows phone 7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7, oauth, windows-phone-7.1, hammock, agfx

Sorry if the question I am asking makes nonsense as I am really new to this. :(

I have a project which is already using Hammock for oAuth (version 1.0) authentication. And then I saw Shawn Burke's awesome [data caching framework AgFx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2011/04/26/using-agfx-with-oauth.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage) and I really want to be able to use it within my project.

But the problem I am having is, with Hammock I can easily make a request by using

```
var request = new RestRequest
{
    Credentials = _credentials,
    Path = "/fav.xml",
    Method = WebMethod.Post
};
```

where I store access token, consumer key, etc. in the _credentials object. And it does its magic for me so I don't need to convert them into the long oauth signature string.

But with AgFx, my understanding is, I need to use WebLoadRequest to request for the data, which looks like this

```
return new WebLoadRequest(loadContext, new Uri(myUri), "POST", "post-data");
```

where "post-data" should be the oauth signature string. Then basically I need to throw away what Hammock gives to me and rewrite the code to get the signature.

I just wonder if there's a better way of doing this? Or should I say if there's a libary I can use to get this signature easily?

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Cheers,

Xin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured it out.

Shawn Burke who created this framework pointed me to the right direction.

Bisically what I've done is I create a HammockLoadRequest which inherits from AgFx's LoadRequest, and in the Execute override, replace the HttpWebRequest with Hammock's RestRequest and that's it.

```
    public class HammockLoadRequest : LoadRequest
{
    public OAuthCredentials Credentials { get; set; }
    public string AuthorityUrl { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a HammockLoadRequest
    /// </summary>
    public HammockLoadRequest(LoadContext loadContext, OAuthCredentials credentials, string authorityUrl)
        : base(loadContext)
    {
        Credentials = credentials;
        AuthorityUrl = authorityUrl;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs the actual get for this request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="result"></param>
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Reliability", "CA2000:Dispose objects before losing scope")]
    public override void Execute(Action<LoadRequestResult> result)
    {
        PriorityQueue.AddNetworkWorkItem(
            () =>
            {
                var client = new RestClient
                {
                    Authority = this.AuthorityUrl,
                    HasElevatedPermissions = true
                };

                var restRequest = new RestRequest
                {
                    Credentials = this.Credentials,
                    Path = "/xxx.json",
                };

                restRequest.AddParameter("count", "5");
                restRequest.AddParameter("include_rts", "1");
                //if (sinceId != 0)
                //    request.AddParameter("since_id", sinceId.ToString());

                RestCallback responseHandler = (request, response, userstate) =>
                {
                    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        Helpers.ShowMessage(String.Format("Error Getting Status: {0}", response.StatusCode));
                        return;
                    }

                    // convert string to stream
                    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response.Content);
                    var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                    stream.Close();
                    result(new LoadRequestResult(new MemoryStream(bytes)));
                    return;
                };

                client.BeginRequest(restRequest, responseHandler);
            });
    }
}
```